# Firebase crash: how programmatically upload mapping file?

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase crash is a cool tool but as fair as I know there is not any way to programmatically upload Proguard mapping file via API after a build.

Recently, "automate file uploads" options appairs but no info are actually aviable in the [learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) link.

[image]

Does anyone know something more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 15th December the Crash Reporting plugin was released by google: it will generate a gradle task that performs the upload of  ProGuard mappings file to Firebase Crash.

Here the steps to use it: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this looks to be an IOS only feature right now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files.

#### Upload symbol files

In order to view human friendly crash reports, you need to upload symbol files after each build. **This can be done automatically by adding a run script to Xcode.**

Download a service account key to authenticate your uploads. From the Firebase console, select your project and then click Generate New Private Key.
In Xcode, click on your application target, select Build Phases, and click `+` to add a phase.
Select Run Script and add the following content, setting appropriate values for your service account path and GOOGLE_APP_ID:
Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"

Note: If your service account key changes, reset your OAuth credentials by running this command:
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*

Comment: thanks for your hint. It's incredible that this feature is not available for android yet.